# elif using dictionary but without excecute the values

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

Hi let's say that I want to replace a large el-ifs statement by a dictionary.
A simplify version of this is as follows:

```
def functionA(a1, a2, a3):

    results = {
        'case1': a2/a3,
        'case2': 1,
        ...
    }
    return results[a1]
```

so a1 would be a string ('case1' or 'case2' or ...) the problem is in some cases the a3 it maybe 0 so the results dictionary could not be define (in all those cases a1 would not be 'case1'). For instance:

```
functionA('case2', 1.0, 3.0)
Out[81]: 1
functionA('case2', 1.0, 0.0)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

So in the second case I expected 1 but I am getting an error.

A possible solution is:

```
def functionA(a1, a2, a3):
    results = {
        'case1': str(a2) + '/' + str(a3),
        'case2': str(1),
    }

    return eval(results[a1])
```

Since I have a multiple cases with complex calculations, is there any better solution?

Comment: that's a typical case for default parameters. `a3` should have a default, so you don't have to pass 0 when you only need 1 param.

Comment: Or you could use lambda expressions instead of relying on string expressions being evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def functionA(a1, a2, a3):
    results = {
        'case1': a2 / a3 if a3 != 0.0 else a2,
        'case2': 1,
        # ...
    }
    return results[a1]
```

However, I would advise against this approach as the entire dictionary has to be computed first only to pick up a single value.

Instead, if you really want to use dictionaries and have it also efficient, I would suggest:

```
myproc = {
    'case1': lambda a2, a3: a2 / a3 if a3 != 0.0 else a2,
    'case2': lambda a2, a3: 1
}
```

Then:

```
>>> myproc['case1'](2, 3)
0.6666666666666666
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ternary operator** inside your dictionary

```
def functionA(a1, a2, a3):

    results = {
        'case1': a2 if a3==0 else a2/a3,
        'case2': 1
    }
    return results[a1]
```

Link : https://repl.it/NRkd

Comment: To the `downvoter`: If you think there is any issue then you should come upfront and explain.

Comment: I do not think there is anything *fundamentally* wrong with your solution - so +1.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just that one value, you can do it with a simple if-else.

```
def functionA(a1, a2, a3):

     if a3:
        case1_value = a2/a3
     else: 
        case1_value = a2

    results = {
        'case1': case1_value,
        'case2': 1,
        ...
    }
    return results[a1]
```

Or create a dvision function with this if-else condition and use it in your dict value.